# .htaccess for displaying the .html files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have  three files in a folder 'test'

```
one.php
two.php
print.html
```

And i have .htaccess file  in the same folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1\.php [L]
```

if we take the print.html in browser , there will be error , because of .htaccess file, 
for there is no 'print.php' page

How can we solve it , by modifing the .htaccess file. So that  while taking the print.html, it should display in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
#If the request is for a file that exists already on the server, the "$1\.php" rule isn't served. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1\.php [L]
```